# Azure Cosmos DB: Can we access a mongodb instance using No sql API and vice versa?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

**Azure Cosmos DB: Can we access a mongodb instance using No sql API and vice versa?
**

We have a use case where we want to perform reads using mongo client and writes using no sql to the same cosmos db instance? Is it feasible? Are these APIs just layers of abstraction and the data ultimately in the both the cases is the same?

Or is it like MongoDB API and No SQL API have different engines altogether? I see the Azure UI portal is entirely different for both these. So do they converge at some point?

We have a cosmos db instance set up using Mongo DB and tried connecting through no sql API and there is no way we could even connect. Even connection method and connection strings are different.

Mongo API has concept of collections but there is nothing like collections on no sql api side. There are containers and the data modeling hierarchy is different.

Comment: Different endpoints, different SDKs. As for collections: Not sure what you mean, but the term "container" is synonymous with "collection. And the MongoDB API is implemented on top of Cosmos DB's SQL API (which uses containers). What is different, modeling-wise?

Answer (score 1):

No.

It did use to be the case that you could connect to the SQL API Endpoint on Mongo API accounts but this endpoint is no longer accessible on accounts created with later versions of the Mongo API.

Even when this was possible your use case of reads using mongo client and writes using no sql would not have been supported.

The Mongo documents returned by the SQL end point were a SQL API JSON serialisation of the BSON documents (i.e. every original property in the BSON document was returned as a sub document with a type and value). This format was never documented.

As far as I know behind the scenes the documents are stored in this No SQL API format though and the Mongo API gateway performs a translation. This can be seen when collecting some of the diagnostic logs and also leaks in other ways (some of the Mongo commands get mapped to NoSQL API stored procedures so get capped by the 5 second bounded execution limit for example)